# how to solve error "not symbol Imageview"?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

How to solve the error, Could not find ImageView in below image

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `import android.widget.ImageView`

clean the project and then rebuild the project, It should fix that

goto `build>clean project` project then `build>rebuild` project

Comment: hey men testing dont work:(

Comment: try invalide caches/ restart from file menu

Comment: also make sure you include `import android.widget.ImageView`

Comment: android.widget.ImageView not available!!

Comment: did u try to rebuild the app?

Comment: yes:( dont work

Comment: solved problam.uninstall android studio and reinstall.